# Recover highlighted colors of cells and other formats in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working of windows 10, I have a problem with my excel sheet. Last week I worked on an excel sheet with some formats and highlighted (colored) some rows and saved it. Today when I opened the same file, all work was lost somehow. I could not see any color or any changes I have made it in previous week. I am afraid that I should not lose my work. I tried by properties--> previous version but there was no any previous version available. Someone please guide me how can I recover my previous work (or version of excel sheet).

Thank you.

Comment: How did you color cells? Manually or use conditional formatting?

Comment: Hi @Lee I colored them manually, but I noticed now I saved as CSV file (just checked file format). Is there any way to recover previous version ?

Answer (score 1):

CSV files don't support colors and formatting (and more). It's just a text file with the columns separated by a certain character and the rows separated by newlines.

[image: Image: CSV file example]

I tested it myself and sadly excel doesn't even warn you when you save a CSV with colors or formatting, which is a bit disappointing.

Because a CSV file ignores colors and formatting, I don't think there's a way to restore your work. But be sure you save the file as an Excel file (.xslx) the next time.
You can convert your CSV file to a xslx file by pressing `Save As` and then you have to choose `Excel Workbook` as the file type (on Windows 10):

[image: Image: Save As Excel Workbook]

Comment: Yes I recognized it and I did everything again and saved with.xlsx extension this time. Thanks for your time.